# Calculate the line integral $∫ _C (-x ^ 2y) dx + (y ^ 2 x) dy$ that is on the triangle formed by the lines $y = x$, $x = 1$ such that $0 ≤ y ≤ 1$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Calculate the line integral $∫ _C (-x ^ 2y) dx + (y ^ 2 x) dy$ that is on the triangle formed by the lines $y = x$, $x = 1$ such that $0 ≤ y ≤ 1$.

I resolve this problem with Green theorem. If $P(x,y)=-x^2y$ and $Q(x,y)=y^2x$ then $∂Q/∂x-∂P/∂y=y^2-x^2$ finally $I=∬_D(y^2-x^2 )dx dy$, where $D$ is the triangle formed by the lines $y = x$, $x = 1$ such that $0 ≤ y ≤ 1$.

$I=∫_0^1∫_0^y(y^2-x^2)dx dy=∫_0^1[xy^2-\frac{x^3}{3}]_0^y dy=∫_0^1\frac{2y^3}{3}dy=[\frac{2y^4}{12}]_0^1=\frac{1}{6}$

The line integral is $\frac{1}{6}$ its correct my result????

Answer (score 0):

Your procedure is correct except for a sign. You have

$$\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} = y^2, \frac{\partial P}{\partial y} = -x^2,$$

therefore

$$\int\limits_{C} (-x^2y) \, dx + (y^2 x) \, dy = \int_0^1 \int_0^y y^2 -(-x^2) \, dx \, dy = \int_0^1 \int_0^y y^2 +x^2 \, dx \, dy.$$

Except for that, your path is correct. You know how to continue from here, from what you showed above.